# How do I rename a root project folder without hindering my team?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-commit, pull-request

The root folder of our repository has a space in it.
I'd like to make a pull-request that replaces this space with an underscore.

As you know, git does not store directories; only filenames.  Therefore, this change will affect every source file in our codebase.

How can I make this change while giving my coworkers the least amount of problems?

All of our developers branch off of a single branch named `dev`, and my change will also need to occur on a sub-branch of `dev`.

---

Here are my desired goals, and current restrictions.

**goals:**

- *minimal hindrance on other developers*.   (We have hundreds of active 
  branches, some of which are pull-requests).
- *preserve history.*   (Ideally, I'd like this change to showup as a
  rename, or a move on the individual file's history).
- *minimal merge conflicts* (if possible)
- *avoid unintentional side effects* (there may be details I'm not aware of.  I should note that we have developers on both windows and linux- although this is not a case sensitive file change.)

**restrictions:**

- I don't have access to directly change the `dev` or `master` branch.
- cannot perform any force pushes (so I won't be able to rewrite history).

Comment: you can simply rename the folder. Git does not mofify the file, but take into account only the change of file name, so also with many files the commit is cheap. If you want to avoid some possible merge conflics you can cherry-pick this commit to other branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the directory using the `git mv` command.  This will work as expected, and preserve history, etc.  Even if other changes occur to the files under this directory hierarchy before your rename is merged, it shouldn't cause any problems.

First, rename the directory:

```
git mv olddir newdir
```

Then use `git commit` to commit the change.

Comment: Ok, that's good to hear.  We had trouble in the past where we lost all of our history from moving code to a different directory.  I suspect that instead of a move, someone had git record both a deletion and a creation.